# What unix permissions do I need?

Tags: unix, permissions, chmod

I have a directory that hangs off root:

`/data/my/folder/here/` and 
`/data/my/folder/herealso/`

I wish all users to be able to write files to the `here` and `herealso` directories. But limit (as much as possible) their ability to do anything else.

What permissions do I need to set for `data`,`my`,`folder`,`here` and `heralso` directories to achieve this?

**EDIT:** I am after `here` and `herealso` to be write-only directories for all users. Since someone has recursively set `/data` to `777` permissions, I also I need the permissions set for the prior directories.

Comment: What do you mean by "anything else"? With traditional Unix permissions, you have to give write access to the directory if you want users to be able to create files (and subdirectories). Can you use ACLs?

Comment: I would prefer that they aren't allowed to read any files in the directory or execute anything in the directory.

Comment: So, in essence you want a write-only directory for users? What real problem are you trying to solve, i.e. why do you need such a directory? Please [edit] and clarify your question. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I want a write only directory for all users.

Answer (score 1):

The directories above `here` need just to be traversable so it's enough to

```
chmod o+x /data
chmod o+x /data/my
chmod o+x /data/my/folder
```

and then allow everybody to write (but not to read) on the lowest level

```
chmod 733 /data/my/folder here herealso
```

And if you want to automatically change the owner of the files to the owner of `here`

```
chmod 4733 /data/my/folder here herealso
```

Answer (score 0):

I'ts pretty simple, fist go to that directory by typing(in a terminal):

```
cd /data/my/folder
```

Now if you wish all users to be able to write and read files from those directories, type:

```
chmod 722 here herealso
```

That's all!
Edit:
If you want the user only to be able to write to the folders, replace 766 with 722
Here is the explanation of numbers:
The first seven means the owner of the dir can do anything(that's normal)
The second digit are permissions for the users in the same group as the owner.
The last one is for the other users.
Remember this:
Read=4 ;Write=2; Execute=1;
To set an property, just add the numbers coresponding to the permisssions you want to set.
For example, If you want read + write, do : 4 + 2 = 6;(Read and write)
Write-only: 2
Read-only: 4;
Write  and execute: 2 + 1 = 3
Sorry for my misunderstanding. Hope it helps

Comment: I was under the impression that `777` permissions gave everyone permission to do anything.

Comment: The OP just mentioned in a comment that they don't want others to read the file, and not give permissions to delete either.